# If $f(x) = 3x^2-x + 2$, find $f(a)$ and $[f(a)]^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x) = 3x^2-x^2$, find $f(a)$ and $[f(a)]^2$ [image]

Also, $2f(a) = 3x2(a)^2-2(a)+2 = 6a^2-2a+2$

The book says the answer is $6a^2-2a+4$. Why is that? Is the book wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful if you used LaTeX formatting.

Comment: What is $F(a)$? Fourier transform? Laplace? Didn't you lost some important?

Comment: you forgot to distribute $2f(a) = 2(3a^2 -a + 2) = 6a^2 - 2a + 4.$ the answer in the book is right.

Comment: But the 2 is outside f(x), for example if I have f(2) = 3(2)-(2)+2=6 I do not place the inside the parenthesis. So why should I do so now?

Answer (score 0):

what you are computing in your work sheet is $f(f(a).$ that is usually is different from $[f(a)]^2.$  you were asked to compute $[f(a)]^2 = (3a^2 - a + 2)^2 = 9a^4 + \dots +4.$